# Getting properties from wrong component in CanDeactivateGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following the component-specific `can-deactivate.guard.ts` example found here: https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes

This guard accesses properties from another component, and I am struggling to get that to fully work with my app.

I have a container called `MessagesComponent` and a child component called `FormComponent`. I'm importing the child component into the guard the same way the example is doing with `CrisisDetailComponent`. My problem is that when I try to access properties from `FormComponent`, the only ones that are actually available to me or the ones coming from my container (MessagesComponent), which I'm not importing into the guard. How do I access the properties from my child component instead? Here is my code:

**guard:**

```
import { FormComponent } from '../components/form/form.component';
...

export class CanDeactivateGuard
    implements CanDeactivate<FormComponent> {
    constructor(
        public dialog: MatDialog,
    ) {}
    canDeactivate(
        component: FormComponent,
    ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        console.log('component', component);
        ...
    }
}
```

**routing:**

```
...
{
  path: 'messages',
  component: MessagesComponent,
  canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
},
...
```

Everything that comes back from my console log is properties from `MessagesComponent`. Why is that happening when I'm importing `FormComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are importing the FormComponent as a type in the CanDeactivateGuard. But you are passing the MessagesComponent. Maybe Angular could throw an error but that is not happening.

In order to clarify, I wrote some code.

```js
    component: MessagesComponent, // this is the component which you're passing to canDeactivate
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard], // you are passing the messages component to the canDeactivate method

    ...

    canDeactivate(
        component: FormComponent, // <- you have FormComponent as a type, but this method actually is receiving MessagesComponent
    )
```

If you want to see your form component on the browser console, you need to pass it.

```js
    component: FormComponent,
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],

    ...

    canDeactivate(
        component: FormComponent, // <- now you can see your form component, and the type is useful to see all the properties and methods which form component has inside itself
    )
```

In your case, you could use the view child decorator to get the child component and use it in the guard.

```js
    export class MessagesComponent {
      @ViewChild(FormComponent) formComponent: FormComponent;
    }

    ...

    component: MessagesComponent,
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard], 

    ...

    canDeactivate(
        component: MessagesComponent,
    ) {
      console.info('magic', component.formComponent);
    }
```